# Finding a specific anchor tag in HTML/navigating website when web scraping with VBA

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping

I'm doing some web scraping with VBA and I have a webpage that has two tabs built into the web page, each tab containing a table with data. One tab opens by default, and the data in the other tab doesn't load unless the tab is clicked, therefore it's not even available in the HTML code until then. I'm looking for a way to click the button using VBA code. the button that opens the other tab seems to be under an href attribute in an a tag, like this:

`<a href="">Rigs</a>`

However, I don't know which anchor tag it is in the html code, otherwise you could just do

`buttonElement = ie.document.getelementsbytagname("a")(56)`

to identify it (if it were, for example, the 57th anchor tag).

My idea is to loop through all the a tags and then identify the tag by its contents somehow, something like this:

```
 For Each aTag In IE.document.getElementsByTagName("a")
        If InStr(1, aTag.href, "Rigs", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
            Set buttonElement = aTag
            Exit For
        End If
    Next aTag
```

I still have no idea how to click it once I find it. buttonElement.click ? Please advise.

I've tried looking through the html to try to find the a tag, counting as I go to identify it. I'm using F12 developer tools in Internet Explorer to look through the HTML code.

I've also tried to loop through the HTML, as shown.

Comment: `aTag.Click` should do it, depending on what handler is attached to the element.

Comment: Also, it looks like "Rigs" is the innerText for your link, not the href attribute.